# setuptools disable PEP3149 ABI tagging for single C Extensions

Tags: python, setuptools

Inside my application I would like to switch between different implementations at runtime (mostly for CPU dispatching when using SIMD). For this reason I use the following structure in my Python C Extension:

```
module/
├── simd_dispatch/
│   ├── impl_avx2.so
│   └── impl_sse2.so
└── my_extensions.cpython-*.so
```

My best attempt to achieve this using setuptools is to build the module using the py_limited_api.

```py
Extension(
  name='module.simd_dispatch.impl_avx2',
  ...
  py_limited_api=True
),
Extension(
  name='module.my_extensions',
  ...
)
```

This way the shared library would be named `impl_avx2.abi3.so`.
However the library does not use the Python C API, so it would be preferred to disable the abi tagging for this single library completely. I could not find any way to achieve this (without mocking internals of setuptools).

Is there any way to disable the abi tagging?

Comment: If it's not using *any* of the Python C API, why are you building it as an extension? If it's not using Python at all, you either build it externally then bundle it in a wheel, or you use something like [`setuptools_dso`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-dso/) or the like to integrate support for building of non-Python shared objects into `setup.py` files.

Comment: In this case `my_extensions` uses the C API, but `impl_avx2` does not. I could not find a different way to build a shared library using setuptools.

Comment: Yeah, the solution is to build the `impl_*.so` files with `setuptools_dso` or build them separately (with a `Makefile` or the like) and packaging the built `.so` files into the wheel you distribute. Trying to build them as extensions means they will be linked to Python, and will get ABI tagged.

Comment: I did not know about `setuptools_dso`. This appears to be the perfect solution for this use case.